# VBA - IF statement does not work

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

Sometimes I wonder why I even program anymore or why I use VBA... I have following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    bSuccess = modGenerateGRList.GenerateGRList

    bSuccess = False

    If bSuccess Then
        CommandButton1.Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

It keeps deleting my button. It's supposed to delete my button when the called funktion was successfull. How can `If bSuccess Then` or `If bSuccess = True Then` result to true?

I used `MsgBox bSuccess` one line before the if, to show me that bSuccess was false and it would still delete my button.

When I delete the line `bSuccess = modGenerateGRList.GenerateGRList`, my code works fine. How can the function `modGenerateGRList.GenerateGRList` influence my code?

// Edit

I realized, that even after I put a comment mark before

```
CommandButton1.Select
Selection.Delete
```

it would still delete my button.

I saved my changes, killed all my Word process and it still deletes my button. It seems to execute old code somehow, even if I run it on a different PC.

Comment: Is `modGenerateGRList.GenerateGRList ` returning False as Boolean or as string "False"  `function GenerateGRList() as Boolean`  Can you add the function code also.

Comment: Public Function GenerateGRList() As Boolean

Comment: what happens if you comment out that code completely, close, save, reopen?  I suspect this isn't the version of the code that's running, you have another copy somewhere else in VBA.

Comment: Are you sure it this code that is running, have you tried a breakpoint?

Comment: Does `CommandButton1` still exist before you get to the `If` statement?  (It seems as if your `GenerateGRList` function is deleting the button.)

Comment: Until you post your `GenerateGRList` function (as requested by @Nathan_Sav yesterday), there isn't much anyone will be able to do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you are running a VBA code, that you do not know where is it coming from or you have some global variables that are constantly somehow redefining, follow these two steps:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
- Write `End` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That should kill anything.

Answer (score 0):

When weird stuff like this happens I reach for this VBA decompiler... In my experience it has worked on many occasions for issues like what you describe.

Give it a shot: http://cpap.com.br/orlando/VBADecompilerMore.asp